# macOS на vmware для разработки - на сколько эффективно?

Tags: windows, xcode, macos, mobile-development, vmware

Увлекаюсь разработкой мобильных приложений под ios, ответа на свой вопрос в интернете не нашел, поэтому хочу спросить прямо)

macOS запускаю через vmware workstation с ноутбука (i7-4510U, 8 gb ram). Долгое время наблюдались подтормаживания и лаги, в следствие чего виртуалка работала не совсем шустро, а если помимо Xcode открыть safari и запустить видео - ситуация становилась еще хуже.

Поставил вместо еще 8gb оперативной памяти в итоге стало 16gb. Виртуалка стала чувствовать себя чуть лучше, но все равно фризы и подвисания (да и в целом медленная работа macOS) остались.

Собственно вопрос - если собрать полноценный ПК с мощным процессором (скажем i7-9700K или i5-8600K) и с 16/32gb ram - сильно ли улучшит это ситуацию? Будет ли система в виртуалке (при данной конфигурации ПК) работать так же хорошо, как и на обычном mac?

Понимаю что под эти цели можно купить macbook и счастью предела не будет, но чисто теоретически, на сколько вариант, описанный мною выше, имеет шансы на успех?

Comment: i7-9700K  в 4,5 раза мощнее i7-4510U. конечно, ситуация будет получше. Но стоит заметить, что не только проц влияет на производительность. Жесткий диск тоже существенно важен. xcode сам лично будет требовать достаточно ОЗУ для нормального функционирования.

Comment: Забыл уточнить - на данный момент в ноутбуке стоит ssd на 500gb + hdd на 1tb (виртуалка и образ macOS установлены на ssd). В конфигурации ПК также планирую использовать ssd

Comment: AMD для таких задач лучше, ядер больше, потоков больше, частоты выше, с виртуализацией так же хорошо как и у Intel (хотя i7-9700K достойный выбор). Добавить достойное количество ОЗУ + SSD как писали выше и будет работать отлично. А VMware Workstation бесплатная или Pro (платная)?

Comment: У меня i7 6-го + 24Gb ОЗУ (пока что), и SSD на всех системах, 4 сервера на виртуалках висит и все работает отлично. Так что задуманный апгрейд себя окупит сполна. Мак конечно, это Мак, тут все понятно. Но и на Linux-системах все также работает плавно

Answer (score 1):

MacOS будет себя хорошо чувствовать и на вашем ноут, если поставите его хакинтошем. По соседству без проблем встанет Win/Linux система.

Comment: Для разработки под iOS  лучше сразу переходи на mac.